# Multiple ItemList markups on a page are not allowed

Tags: wordpress, schema.org

I am trying to apply schema on my blog. But Google Structured Data Testing Tool gives me this error "Multiple ItemList markups on a page are not allowed." When I finalized everything.

I am using ItemList for products (as this is an Amazon product review site) and FAQs too (that also uses item list) at this page `https://www.showerheads.review/best-shower-heads/`

You can see the results in the below image.
[image]

Any way to get out of this problem so that I can use both the FAQs and Product item too.

Comment: Can you create separate pages for the FAQs and the products?